# Running Drupal API Scripts offline

Tags: drush, external-scripts

I want to run some maintenance scripts against a Drupal 7 system. These scripts will call the Drupal API to use things like `EntityFieldQuery`, `node->save` and so on. I could create a module called `maintenance_scripts` which has a forms interface to launch the scripts with and to display their output, but I'd rather just run a script from the command line. Is this possible?

Comment: Using drush you can create your custom commands it's very easy. http://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-create-drush-command/

Comment: That's a great article thanks. So I'd have to create a whole new module (with all the required infrastructure of .info files etc), or add hooks into an existing module, in order to run my Drush script? Is there any easier way?

Comment: If you want to create a stand-alone Drush script, you can put it in ~/.drush, or in __DRUPAL_ROOT__/drush.  Don't forget to run `drush cc drush` after creating a new Drush command; otherwise, Drush won't refresh its cache of command file locations, and your new command will not be found.

Comment: You can use an existing module you have developed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to write an entire Drush command just to run some php code.  Use:

`drush php-eval '$a = callSomeFunction(); print $a;'`

or:

`drush php-script /path/to/script.php`

Drush will bootstrap your site and run your code.